# Why does NOTIFY_STOP in the keyboard notifier chain not affect X11?

Tags: linux-kernel, x11, xorg

I am trying to write a Linux kernel module that will observe keyboard events and modify/block some of them. I'm using the keyboard notifier chain (with `register_keyboard_notifier`). Returning `NOTIFY_STOP` to block a keyboard event works in the virtual terminal. However, X11 (X.org on Ubuntu 16.04) is unaffected. Why?

How can I do something similar in a way that affects X11?

Comment: Well, X uses event devices ('evdev') so it probably captures the keyboard event before they reach your code. Your code probably sits between the keyboard interrupt and the terminal code ('tty' pseudo terminal) so that's why it works for your virtaul terminal.

Comment: @JvO: [This diagram](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/essentiallinuxdevicedrivers/final/images/YTNyaWQ3ODBzOS9jL2VnbXRwNjQ5NWEzMi9yZzE1ZmkwcGdmaS4wLzFoaWc3c2M-.jpg) made me think that those event devices were downstream of keyboard.c and the notifier chain, but clearly I'm missing something.